# Use position:absolute within a three levels menu to display the last two levels on the right of each other avoiding stack them on each other

Tags: html, css, css-position

The following code will describe this situation:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0 0 1% 5%;
  font-size: 18px;

}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}
.drop-down {
  position: absolute;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
.drop-down .level {
  left: 114px;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.drop-down li {
  display: block;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.drop-down .level.grey {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li class="drop">list item 1</li>
   <div class="drop-down">
    <ul>
     <li>list item sub 2</li>
     <div class="drop-down level">
      <ul>
       <li>list item sub-sub 3</li>
       <li>list item sub-sub 3</li>
       <li>list item sub-sub 3</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <li>list item sub 3</li>
     <div class="drop-down level grey">
      <ul>
       <li>list item sub-sub 3</li>
       <li>list item sub-sub 3</li>
       <li>list item sub-sub 3</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <li>list item sub 4</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <li class="drop">list item 2</li>
   <li class="drop">list item 3</li>
   <li class="drop">list item 4</li>
   <li class="drop">list item 5</li>
   <li class="drop">list item 6</li>
   <li class="drop">list item 7</li>
   <li class="drop">list item 8</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</body>
```

I'm building a three levels menu that, when you hover on each element on each level, it will open the next level corresponding to the element that you hover.

This is what I would like to achieve more or less:

[image]

I've not arrived yet at the point where I'm adding the on-hover property because I'm dealing with a positioning problem. The elements (`li`) on the first level have an inline positioning, the second level elements (`li`) instead are blocked element piled up one on each other and the same thing happens in the third level.

Now the third level is on the right of the second level so, if I use a `position:absolute` property and then `top:0` for example, each sub-third-level (let's suppose that we have more than one third level menu item) will hide the next sublevel-3 like it happens in this picture:

[image]

Essentially I would like to avoid this problem so if you hover on `list-item-sub-2` I would like to open only the div with the class `drop-down.level` and when I hover on the next element list `list-item-sub-3` I want to open the div with the class `drop-down.level.grey` in a different position that match with `list-item-sub-3` (a little bit down to the previous list).

I would like to use only css but like I said, if I use a `position:absolute` property on each element with a value like `top:10px` or `top:2%` every element will put themselves on each other, if I use a `position:relative` instead, every element will nested on their father of the upper level.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, [`<ul>`s may only contain `<li>`, `<script>`, and `<template>` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element:concept-element-content-model). The submenu `<ul>`s should be children of their associated `<li>`s. With that change in place, we can position the `<ul>`s absolutely inside their `<li>`s based on their depth in the menu hierarchy and drop all the classes:

```css
nav ul {
  margin: 0 0 1% 5%;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  /* All <ul>s are positioned relative to their parent <li> */
  position: relative;
  /* No bullets */
  list-style: none;
  /* Without word wrapping, menus are as wide as they need to be */
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Top-level list's items are inline */
nav>ul>li {
  display: inline;
}

/* Second-level lists are below their parent <li> */
nav>ul>li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

/* Third-level lists and deeper are right of their parent <li> */
nav ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}

.grey {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>File</li>
    <li>Edit</li>
    <li>
      View
      <ul>
        <li>
          Toolbars
          <ul class="grey">
            <li>Menu Bar</li>
            <li>Bookmarks Toolbar</li>
            <li>Customize...</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          Sidebar
          <ul>
            <li>Bookmarks</li>
            <li>History</li>
            <li>Synced Tabs</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Zoom</li>
        <li>Page Style</li>
        <li>Text Encoding</li>
        <li>Full Screen</li>
        <li>Enter Reader View</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>History</li>
    <li>Bookmarks</li>
    <li>Tools</li>
    <li>Help</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You'll need JavaScript for the hover effects, because [usable flyout menus are challenging](http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown) and CSS's `:hover` pseudo-class isn't up to the task (spoilered for annoying animated GIF):

> [image: Mousing outside the highlighted menu item of a naive flyout on the way to a submenu item immediately closes the submenu]

Have you considered a [mega menu](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mega-menus-work-well/)?